# How to have different headers.php files based on the display page

Tags: php, theme-development

With the `get_header()` function, if I have an `header.php` and an `header-news.php`, can I use the second file only when a single post of the nesw category is displayed? I have a one page wordpress website where the only page will be the news category archive and the sigle news categorized posts that are using the `single.php` file template. The menu links are anchor tags so if the user navigate away from home by clicking on a news, I need that the menu can redirect it back to the home where all the contents are published. Also I need some suggestion on how to paginate my category archive. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this header in single.php

```
<?php get_header('news'); ?>
```

let me know if still facing the issue.

Comment: It wasn't really an issue, I've asket to be sure that I can do the same you did in the answer, I've used this trick only one time for a woocommerce custom theme and it worked. Thanks for the help